# IllegalArgumentException: Trying to execute a remote operation asynchronously without a handler to the listener's thread

Tags: java, android, owncloud

I want to upload in a service

I was using this code sample library for uploading owncloud.org

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnRemoteOperationListener, OnDatatransferProgressListener {`
private Handler mHandler;     
private OwnCloudClient mClient; `
   private void startUpload() {
    File upFolder = new File(getCacheDir(), getString(R.string.upload_folder_path));
    File fileToUpload = ; 
    String remotePath =; 
    String mimeType =;
    UploadRemoteFileOperation uploadOperation = new UploadRemoteFileOperation(fileToUpload.getAbsolutePath(), remotePath, mimeType);
    uploadOperation.execute(mClient, this, mHandler);
}
```

I want to upload in a service end i write this:

public class MyService extends Service implements OnRemoteOperationListener {
    private Handler mHandler;

```
private OwnCloudClient mClient;

public MyService() {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
  return null;

}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // Let it continue running until it is stopped.


    if (intent != null) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();

        if (ACTION.equals(action)) {



            Uri serverUri = Uri.parse(server);
            mClient = OwnCloudClientFactory.createOwnCloudClient(serverUri, this, true);
            mClient.setCredentials(
                    OwnCloudCredentialsFactory.newBasicCredentials(
                            username, pass
                    )
            );


            try {
                actionSendList(dest);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }  return START_STICKY;}




private void actionSendList(String dest) throws IOException {


        //String remotePath = FileUtils.PATH_SEPARATOR +"/nuovo/"+ files.gString mimeType = getString(R.string.sample_file_mimetype);
        UploadRemoteFileOperation uploadOperation = new UploadRemoteFileOperation(files.get(i).getAbsolutePath(), remotePath , null);
        //uploadOperation.addDatatransferProgressListener(context);
        uploadOperation.execute(mClient,this,mHandler);


    }


}

    @Override
    public void onRemoteOperationFinish (RemoteOperation caller, RemoteOperationResult result){
        if (!result.isSuccess()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.todo_operation_finished_in_fail, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.i("service", "fail");
        }
    }
```

}
the app crash on  uploadOperation.execute(mClient,this,mHandler);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an intent service. The onHandleIntent method will be executed on a background thread and you are trying to execute AsyncTask from a background thread which is wrong. AsyncTask must be executed from main thread. Main thread will have a default handler associated with it. You have to use the Service component of Android not IntentService.

Comment: I have not solved. i created handler in service android and call 
        uploadOperation.execute(mClient,this,mHandler); in start command but l'app crah

Comment: I had forgotten   mHandler = new Handler();